# Parsing HTML <Tag> into ios

Tags: iphone, ios, html, ipad

i am Parsing HTML Tag into iOS using Hpple. i am able to parse the data where the HTML Tag is

```
 <div id="NewsPageSubTitle">
         <p><**span** hi how are you>
```

Using ios code:

```
NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"//div[@id='NewsPageArticle']/p/span ";
 NSArray *tutorialsNodes = [tutorialsParser searchWithXPathQuery:tutorialsXpathQueryString];
```

but in few case i don't have span, imean the string in html is accessed by tag "p" directly like:

```
<div id="NewsPageSubTitle">
             <p>< hi how are you>
```

Here I am using ios code as:

```
NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"//div[@id='NewsPageArticle']/p ";
     NSArray *tutorialsNodes = [tutorialsParser searchWithXPathQuery:tutorialsXpathQueryString];
```

but here i am getting a blank data in response.

can any one let me know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since sometimes the para tag has span and sometimes it does not, I would suggest trying to handle that by looping over the children

```
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
    NSData  * data      = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    TFHpple * tutorialsParser       = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];

    NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"//div[@id='NewsPageSubTitle']";
    NSArray *tutorialsNodes = [tutorialsParser searchWithXPathQuery:tutorialsXpathQueryString];

    for (TFHppleElement * element in tutorialsNodes) {
        NSLog(@"%@", element);
        NSLog(@"%@", [element tagName]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [element attributes]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [element children]);
        for (TFHppleElement *childElement in [element children]) {
                NSLog(@"%@", childElement);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check with this: https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser

This will provide the HTML Parser for iphone sdk.

More help on:

[this blog](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/02/24/parsing-html-iphone-development/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242444/memory-leaking-iphone-sdk/5242803#5242803).

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"New Folder 2"];
NSData  * data      = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSFileHandle *readHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];

NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[readHandle readDataToEndOfFile] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


TFHpple * Parser       = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];

NSString *query = @"//p";

NSArray *nodes = [Parser searchWithXPathQuery:query];
for (TFHppleElement *item in nodes)
    {
       NSLog(@"Title : %@", item.content);

            NSLog(@"URL : %@", [item.attributes valueForKey:@"href"]);
      }
```