# UIWebview is not loading youtube video in iFrame

Tags: ios, objective-c, iframe, uiwebview

I'm trying to load an HTML string into a `UIWebView`. The HTML contains an `iframe`, but it does not load in the webview.

Here is my code,

```
webDescription = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 255,self.view.bounds.size.width, 20)];
[[webDescription scrollView] setBounces: NO];
webDescription.delegate = self;
NSString *myDescriptionHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                                   "<head> \n"
                                   "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                                   "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@; COLOR:#111111; background-color:transparent; padding:10px 5px 15px 20px;}\n"
                                   "</style> \n"
                                   "</head> \n"
                                   "<body>%@</body> \n"
                                   "</html>", @"MyriadPro-Regular", [NSNumber numberWithInt:12], _group.gro_content];
[webDescription setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[webDescription setOpaque:NO];
[webDescription loadHTMLString:myDescriptionHTML baseURL:nil];
[scrollView addSubview:webDescription];
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have You Done it then please share your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString *)youtubeUrl frame:(CGRect)frame {
    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
                                <html><head>\
                            <style type=\"text/css\">\
                            body {\
                                background-color: transparent;\
                                color: white;\
                            }\
                            </style>\
                            </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                            <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
                            width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
                            </body></html>";
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, youtubeUrl, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
    UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [playerview addSubview:videoView];
}
```

Comment: the problem is that I get the iframe beck from my webservice. And it looks like this --> <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="300" scrolling="no" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/MdpQh4kys30" width="500"></iframe></p>

Comment: so first you need to parse html check this que http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966071/parse-html-in-objective-c

Comment: Even This one is not working if I use.NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, @"http://www.youtube.com//embed//5Qg-gjG3LJU",300.0, 200.0]; Any Idea.