# How to create Play/Pause touch action in <video></video> tag for iPhone?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html5-video

In my iOS app i'm using html5  tag for playing video in inline.

My code:

```
<video onclick="a()" id="myVideo" src="'+item.video_name+'" allowfullscreen width="280" height="280" webkit-playsinline loop></video>
```

How to set touch action for play/pause on video. when I create onclick function on video tag, its not work. Is there any way to create  play/pause touch action on video.
Help me ..

Answer (score 0):

If you load a UIWebView with an iFrame string that contains a video it should be automatically handled by the UIWebView.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371952/uiwebview-is-not-loading-youtube-video-in-iframe) question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have used UIWebView for loading my HTML file. Video plays inline correctly when I using "controls" in video tag. But without displaying the controls option I want play/pause video by touch action.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` property of you UIWebView to `NO`.