# Parse NSString with regex in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I have the following input:

```
<table class="fiche_table_caracter"><tbody>
<tr>
    <td class="caracteristique"><strong>Design</strong></td>
    <td>Classique (full tactile)</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="caracteristique"><strong>Système d'exploitation (OS)</strong></td>
    <td>iOS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="caracteristique"><strong>Ecran</strong></td>
    <td>4,7'' (1334 x 750 pixels)<br />16 millions de couleurs</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="caracteristique"><strong>Mémoire interne</strong></td>
    <td>128 Go, 1 Go RAM</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="caracteristique"><strong>Appareil photo</strong></td>
    <td>8 mégapixels</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I need to extract only the content of the `<td>` tags. This is what I did:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<tr*>(.*?)</tr>" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];

            NSArray *myArray = [regex matchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])] ;
            UA_log(@"counttt: %d", [myArray count]);
            NSMutableArray *matches = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[myArray count]];

            for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in myArray) {
                NSRange matchRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
                [matches addObject:[str substringWithRange:matchRange]];
                NSLog(@"Regex output:%@", [matches lastObject]);
                NSString * str2 = [matches lastObject];
                NSRegularExpression *regex2 = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<td*>(<strong>)?(.*?)(</strong>)?</td>" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];

                NSArray *myArray2 = [regex2 matchesInString:str2 options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str2 length])] ;
                UA_log(@"counttt: %d", [myArray2 count]);
                NSMutableArray *matches2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[myArray2 count]];

                for (NSTextCheckingResult *match2 in myArray2) {
                    NSRange matchRange2 = [match2 rangeAtIndex:1];
                    [matches2 addObject:[str2 substringWithRange:matchRange2]];
                    NSLog(@"Regex2 output:%@", [matches2 lastObject]);
                    NSString * lastObject2 = [matches2 lastObject];

                }

            }
```

The issue I get is that I would like to set the tag `<Strong>` as optional but it doesn't work. With this code, I could extract the "tr" but not the content of the "td".

Please help!

I would like to extract:

```
1-

Design

Classique (full tactile)

2-

Système d'exploitation (OS)

iOS

3-

Ecran

16 millions de couleurs

4-

Mémoire interne

128 Go, 1 Go RAM
```

Comment: Can you edit you question to include what you want to extract?

Comment: Try using 1) `(?s)<tr[^<]*>(.*?)</tr>`, and 2) `(?s)(?:<td\\b[^<]*>|\\G(?!^))(?:<[^<]+>)?(?!\\s+)([^<]*)(?:<[^<]+>)?`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cM4yC5/1).

Comment: Try reading xml string to NSDictionary by using [xml parser](https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader) and then you can extract any values inside that. This will be a good approach rather than trying with string.

Comment: @stribizhev: hi stribizhev, thank you for your solution, and the demo. it works great !! please post your solution as an answer so i can confirm it as the correct one. i am new in stack overflow so i can not vote your comment.

Comment: @Mireil Please do not accept a regex-based answer. **Regular expressions are not suited for parsing XML, even if you think they are.** You should use an **XML parser** to parse XML. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: @ The Paramagnetic Croissant: What I liked about the Regex solution, is that i shouldn't specify the XML tags and my XML tree has dynamic tags so I couldn't rely on the XML parsing. Because as i said, i dont have control on the tag names but only the tree structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## THE "RIGHT WAY" WITH HTML PARSER

You should know that whenever you have arbitrary HTML, you will need a HTML parser to get information from the HTML code, e.g. [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios)'s parser. Here is an example of using it (note that you want to get the contents of `td` nodes that have `class` attribute set to `caracteristique` - thus, XPath to be used is `@"//tr/td[@class='caracteristique']"`):

```
- (void)loadDataFromHtml {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    TFHpple *parser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:data];
    NSString *XpathQueryString = @"//tr/td[@class='caracteristique']"; // Here, we use the XPath
    NSArray *nodes = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:XpathQueryString];
    for (TFHppleElement *element in nodes) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [element content]);
    }
}
```

See more on this at [Parse HTML in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966071/parse-html-in-objective-c), and [How to Parse HTML on iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios).

## REGEX FIX (SINCE *OP REQUIRES IT*)

Here are fixes for your regular expressions:

The first one should be

```
(?s)<tr[^<]*>(.*?)</tr>
```

With `[^<]*` we make sure we are still inside `<tr>` tag and match all its attributes.

The second regex:

```
(?s)(?:<td\\b[^<]*>|\\G(?!^))(?:<[^<]+>)?(?!\\s+)([^<]*)(?:<[^<]+>)?
```

It matches all texts skipping tags. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cM4yC5/1).

**Explanation:**

- `(?s)` - force single line  mode when `.` matches a newline character
- `(?:<td\\b[^<]*>|(?!^)\\G)` - sets the starting range location at `<td...>` or the end of previous match (`(?!^)\\G`).
- `(?:<[^<]+>)?` - optionally matches a node element of type `<...>`
- `(?!\\s+)([^<]*)` - matches text outside tags that is not whitespace
- `(?:<[^<]+>)?` - optionally matches a node element of type `<...>`

Comment: Once you have time, please re-accept and re-upvote. Thank you.

Comment: done! and thank you very much for your priceless help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [XMLParser](https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader) to read the string by

## import "XMLReader.h"

```
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:data error:&error];
NSArray *trArray = [dict valueForKeyPath:@"table.tbody.tr"];
NSArray *tdArray = [trArray valueForKey:@"td"];
NSInteger i = 1;
for (NSArray *tdItems in tdArray) {
    NSString *stringValue = @"";
    for (NSDictionary *td in tdItems) {
        if ([td valueForKey:@"strong"]) {
            NSDictionary *strong = [td valueForKey:@"strong"];
            if ([strong valueForKey:@"text"]) {
                stringValue = [stringValue stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n %@", [strong valueForKey:@"text"]]];
            }
        } else if ([td valueForKey:@"text"]) {
            stringValue = [stringValue stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n %@", [td valueForKey:@"text"]]];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%d- %@", i, stringValue);
    i++;
}
```