# Swift remove data in HTML tags

Tags: ios, swift

I get data from an API that i render in an `UIWebView`.

Sometimes i get tables that has a set width, example:

```
<table border=\"2\" width=\"624\" height=\"93\" style=\"width: 624px; height: 93px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;\">
```

In this case i want to remove the width in the table tag and in the style.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966071

Comment: How you receive data from server HTML? xml? or Json I mean what is response for the call?